# why would I have water leaking on the bathroom floor when someone takes a bath but not a shower

Tags: plumbing-fixture

Why would I have water leaking on my bathroom floor when someone takes a bath but not a shower?

Comment: When taking a bath does the water come close to the overflow outlet? Does the leak show up before the tub is drained?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the tub has a crack somewhere high and when you take a bath water reaches the crack but when you take a shower it doesn't since the tub doesn't fill up. If it's not a crack it's something related to the level of water in the tub. Could be the overflow drain.

Answer (score 2):

If the tub is in good shape, you probably have a plumbing leak somewhere between the diverter valve and the tub spigot.

Or you have a leak at the overflow drain.